# when is this statement is true?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_i>0$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. It's well known that:

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}a_i\to a \ $(as $n\to\infty)\Longrightarrow a_i\to0$ (as $n\to\infty$)

My question is when is the following statement true:

$\dfrac1n\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}a_i\to 0\ $(as $n\to\infty$) $\Longrightarrow$ $a_i\to0$(as $n\to\infty$)

?

Comment: Note that
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i \to 0 \qquad (n\to\infty), a_i > 0$$
Is unsatisfiable, so you can deduce anything from that...

Comment: Are the $a_i$ supposed to be independent of $n$ or should they be denoted as $a_{i,n}$?

Comment: @user48805: $a_i$ is independent of $n$.

Comment: @AlexR Probably the first well-known part should read $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}a_i\to a$(as $n\to\infty)\Longrightarrow a_i\to0$ (as $n\to\infty$) where $a<\infty$ is some finite limit.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I guess so as well, but this would definately need to be fixed (same for the second part).

Comment: @mac I took the freedom to edit the Question. Does this reflect your concerns? If not, feel freee to revert/correct the edit.

Comment: @AlexR I think it's important that $\sum a_i/n \to0$.

Comment: @AlexR Please, don't edit the answer significantly without the OPs approval.

Comment: If we know that $a_0>a_1>a_2>\dots$ and we know that $\left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n a_i \right)$ converges to zero (not just to a positive limit), then we can conclude that $a_i\to 0$, it seems.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff The edit was not made out-of-the-blue and the first edit was definately necessary, for other concerns, I agree.

Comment: @AlexR I put in a parenthesis in my comment, for clarity. As an example, when the terms are $a_i=\frac{1}{i}$ we have the harmonic series (which diverges). But $\left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n a_i \right)$ still goes to zero in that example.

Answer (score 2):

**ADD** This is from Apostol's "Mathematical Analysis". The work is for series, but you can aapt it for sequences

> Let $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$, $t_=\sum_{k=1}^n ka_k$, $\sigma_n=\frac 1 n\sum_{k=1}^n s_k$. Note $t_n=(n+1)s_n-n\sigma_n$.
>
> *Claim* If $\sum a_n$ is $(C,1)$ summable (i.e. $\sigma_n$ converges), then $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if $t_n=o(n)$.

---

The converse is true, and it is a celebrated theorem of Cesàro. A counterexample to your claim would be $a_{n^2}=1$ and $a_n=2^{-n}$ otherwise.

Comment: @AlexR Ah, ran past that one. Let me fix it.

Comment: Possible fix: $a_n=1/2^n$ otherwise (keeping $a_{n^2}=1$).

Comment: @coffeemath Darn it. Positive.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: I do know it's not true in general.But My question is: under which conditions we can conclude that statement!

Comment: @mac I added something.

Answer (score 1):

A Tauberian theorem which can be deduced from Cesàro's theorem says that if the sums
$$\sigma_n := \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i a_j$$
converge and $\limsup_{n\to\infty} na_n <\infty$, then the partial sums
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$$
converge and the limits coincide.
Thus, under the assumption $\limsup_{n\to\infty} na_n <\infty$, you could get $a_n\to0$ from $\sigma_n\to a$, but the assumption is already stronger than $a_n\to0$ so it's quite pointless.

Comment: In general I know that If $n(a_{n+1}-a_n)\to 0$ then we can conclude $a_n\to a$ from $\sigma_n\to a$. But this assumption is strong!

Comment: One can state something slightly more general: we have the Littlewood version of Tauber's theorem, which states the following: if a sequence of numbers $a_n$ is [Cesaro summable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation) to a number $s$, and if $a_n = O(1/n)$ (which we mean that there exists some number $M$ such that $|na_n| \leq M$ for all $n$), then the partial sums $\sum_{i = 1}^n a_n$ converges also to $s$. Unfortunately, even in this case the assumption $a_n = O(1/n)$ presupposes $a_n \to 0$, so we have rather nothing to prove.

Comment: @WillieWong Just as you stated in the comment, the prerequisites are stonger than the deduction; nonetheless it answers the question ;) thanks for pointing out the erroneous definition of $\sigma_n$